# How can I get WooCommerce attributes to display custom meta/text on selection?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm selling artwork using Wordpress and WooCommerce and I have an attribute for Frame Style. I love that when the user selects a frame I can update the photo with a custom image to match that frame, similarly I'm trying to figure out a way to display custom text based on the users selection.

So to clarify, if someone selects "Black Scoop Frame" I want to be able to have that specific frames size and description display. And if they change their selection to "Red Wood Frame" I want the description to change with it.

WooCommerce allows descriptions to be added to attributes and I have been trying for dayys to figure out how to call that meta data and have it change with the drop down selection change.

Any help or even pointing me in the right direction would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Frst of all, give your options

```
function your_options() {
    $sample_select_options = array(
        '0' => array( 'value' => '0', 'label' => __( '', '_s' ) ),
        '1   ' => array( 'value' => '1   ', 'label' => __( 'Something1', '_s' ) ),
        '2   ' => array( 'value' => '2   ', 'label' => __( 'Something2', '_s' ) );
    return apply_filters( 'your_options', $give_me_options );
}
```

Than set up selecting options on your page

```
<select name="" id="" style="width: 300px;">
        <?php
            $selected = options['give_me_options'];
            $p = '';
            $r = '';

            foreach ( your_options() as $option ) {
                $label = $option['label'];
                if ( $selected == $option['label'] ) // Make default first in list
                    $p .= "\n\t<option style=\"padding-right: 10px;\" selected='selected' value='" . esc_attr( $option['label'] ) . "'>$label</option>";
                else
                    $r .= "\n\t<option style=\"padding-right: 10px;\" value='" . esc_attr( $option['label'] ) . "'>$label</option>";
            }
            echo $p . $r;
        ?></select>
```

And at the end, put action to your page, where to give it and of course save function :)

This is only a guide how to do it, not a specific code.